# JavaScript compute values from input texts on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, autocomplete

In my HTML, I have several input texts where I am putting numbers. According to the values I enter, a JavaScript computes a result. It computes it on value change. The problem is, that I have to click out of the input to submit new value. How can I submit them while typing? (It is more user friendly. Users do not have to figure out, that they have to click outside to submit)

Here's how my values are submitted to the function now

```
$(function () {
    $('select, input').on('change', calculator);
});
```

Comment: Use "keydown" instead of "change".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple events for that,

```
$('select, input').on('keydown blur change',calculator);
```

You need to use change event for `select`.

Comment: I would add `paste` and `drop` as well to the list of events.

Answer (score 1):

Use **keydown()** method.

```
$(function () {
    $('select, input').on('keydown change'calculator);
});
```